# Override: Style next and previous button

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides

I want to style the `next` and `previous buttons` from Joomla! and I already have configured that in my css file, so I've just to add them a class but I don't find the file, where I can override these two buttons. I already looked for the `pagination folder` which contains the two files `link.php` and `links.php` but it seems to be the wrong folder.

Does anyone know, in which file these two buttons(links) could hide?

I appreciate every help and comment!

Comment: `templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/pagination.php`?

Comment: Hello .. I do not have this file

Comment: Which template are you using? I made a mistake in the URL, was supposed to be `html`, not `htm`

Comment: I created my own

Comment: maybe just target them with your css... using [css specifity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: Only thing I'd say is try not to target using ID's in your CSS. The article provided is from 2007 and it's a bad practice. Use classes

Comment: @Lodder, This.Sven: CSS Classes/IDs: Big discussion and a whole other topic. I posted the link as a css specifity reference. You are right underlining this, however I wouldn't call exactly a bad practice that should never happen. Actually IDs can be used, but someone has to be very specific on the way and the volume he uses them. I 'd say if someone styles a whole html page, based on the ids of the various elements, then certainly he doesn't know what he is doing and why he is doing it. Having said that, I still use IDs as selector where it does make sense and seems appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your template, for example in the default *Protostar* template you
 can find this file in:

- **/templates/protostar/html/pagination.php**

If you don't have this file you can create a new one, find the default code here:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/templates/protostar/html/pagination.php

Joomla! includes *Bootstrap* v2.3.2, you can use the css in this version or you can 
use your custom css, here you have the reference:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2

You can incorporate your custom css in your main css or less file in the section related
with pagination, or you can override the css, in some template frameworks we can add
    a custom.css file or similar, check if you have this option.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks @AlexVega! I accepted your answer a bit late because I wasn't online until now